# how to rotate the rectangle in matplotlib patch?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing rotated rectangle using matplotlib but I don't know how to adjust the angle?

```
rect = patches.Rectangle((int(arr[2])-0.5*int(arr[4]),int(arr[3])-0.5*int(arr[5])), int(arr[4]),int(arr[5]),
                        fill=False,
                        edgecolor='g', linewidth=1)
t = matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_around(float(arr[2]), float(arr[3]),\
                float(arr[6])*180/np.pi)

rect.set_transform(t + plt.gca().transData)

plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
```

1 10 3308 261 21 10 -88.363423
this is the data of one car

but the rectangel don't fit it.

[description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2iis.png)

Comment: What are you trying, what is the problem? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the angle of rotation should be -88 degrees.

Negative angles will rotate clockwise. `.rotate_around` expects it's anglular argument to be in radiants.

You're using `float(arr[6])*180/np.pi`, which would convert radiants to degrees, but makes little sense as you already have the angle in degrees.

Instead use

```
float(arr[6])*np.pi/180.
```

or

```
np.deg2rad(float(arr[6]))
```

[image]